# Translating Binding from C# to XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

i can't get this binding working in XAML.

Binding in c# works:

```
public partial class myControl : UserControl
{
    // get singleton instance
    InfoPool Info = InfoPool.Info;

    public myControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Test Binding
        Binding bind = new Binding();
        bind.Source = this.Info;
        bind.Path = new PropertyPath("Time");
        txtInfoTime.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, bind);
    }
}
```

Binding in XAML not:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txtInfoTime" Text="{Binding Path=Time, Source=Info}" />
```

Path and Source are the same, so where is my mistake?

Thx Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the DataContext.

You can just add:

```
DataContext = Info
```

after

```
InitializeComponent();
```

And change XAML to:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txtInfoTime" Text="{Binding Time}" />
```

Comment: If he does that, EVERYTHING in the UserControl will have Info as the DataContext, and there will be no way to bind to something else...

Comment: So this kind of binding is easier I think, cause in don't need to bind to others in this control

Answer (score 5):

You can't translate it to XAML with the exact same properties, because there is no way to reference `this.Info` directly. However, you can achieve the same result by setting a `RelativeSource` :

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txtInfoTime" Text="{Binding Path=Info.Time, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:myControl}}}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i will use the other solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since InfoPool is a singleton instance i would recommend the following:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txtInfoTime" Text="{Binding Path=Time, Source={x:Static ns:InfoPool.Info}}"/>
```

Where `ns` is the xaml-alias for the namespace in which InfoPool is defined. 
No need to mess up your DataContext this way.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your answers I solved the Problem like described below. I post it, because i guess that other beginners in WPF could find it useful.

I have singleton class (InfoPool.cs) wich implements INotifyChangedProperty. It's used to provide appwide bindable properties. This class is used by an ObjectDataProvider in App.xaml. So it's very "easy" to bind to a property

InfoPool.cs (the Singleton code is from http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx 5th Version. I changed the Instance Property to GetInstance() Method, because the OPD needs an Method)

```
public sealed class InfoPool : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    InfoPool()
    {
    }

    public static InfoPool GetInstance()
    {
        return Nested.instance;
    }

    class Nested
    {
        static Nested()
        {
        }

        internal static readonly InfoPool instance = new InfoPool();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
    }

    private String strProp = "default String";
    private Double dblProp = 1.23456;

    public String StrProp
    {
        get { return strProp; }
        set 
        { 
            strProp = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("StrProp"));
        }
    }

    public Double DblProp
    {
        get { return dblProp; }
        set 
        { 
            dblProp = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("DblProp"));
        }
    }
```

The ObjectDataProvider in App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="OPDInfo" ObjectType="{x:Type local:InfoPool}" MethodName="GetInstance" d:IsDataSource="True"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

An here are 2 ways to bind to the OPD

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbprop1" Text="{Binding Path=StrProp, Source={StaticResource OPDInfo}}" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbprop2" Text="{Binding DblProp}" ToolTip="{Binding StrProp}" DataContext="{StaticResource OPDInfo}" />
</StackPanel>
```

That's it. Please comment, cause I'm new to this ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you leave your singleton instance accessor as a property you don't need an ObjectDataProvider.  You can just use the static instance directly.

```
<StackPanel>
<TextBlock x:Name="tbprop1" 
    Text="{Binding Path=StrProp, Source={x:Static local:InfoPool.Instance}}" /> 
</StackPanel>
```